# How to count only letters in string?

Tags: c, loops, c-strings, cs50, isalpha

I am trying to write a program that counts several elements in a string. The first one of those being letters.

The assignment is part of the CS50 week 2 problem set, hence the libraries included.

Using the `while` condition I was able to count every single character, but the code stopped working once I´ve added `isalnum` (which checks if the character is alphanumerical).

What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    string text = get_string("Text: ");
    printf("%s, \n", text);

    int letters = 0;
    while (text[letters] != '\0') {
        if (isalnum(text[letters])) {
            letters++;
        }
    }
    printf("%i \n", letters);
}
```

Comment: You are trying to use `letters` both as an index to your array, and to count how many letters you've come across.  What happens when you come across a character that isn't a letter?

Comment: You'll loop forever as soon as `isalnum(text[letters])` is false. The easiest thing to do is to use two `int`s one a counter for how many alpha characters you have, and the other as the current position in your string.

Comment: Also that you probably should write `return 0` though this is not related to the problem...

Comment: @user12986714 no. `main` is the exception.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers! It finally clicked for me going through your responses on where the loop was supposed to end vs where it was ending.

Comment: @LauraT: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is shown how a correct loop can be defined

```
size_t letters = 0;
for ( size_t i = 0; text[i] !='\0'; i++ )
{
    if ( isalnum( ( unsigned char )text[i] ) )
    {
       letters++;
    }
}

printf( "%zu\n", letters );
```

If you want to use a while loop then it can look for example like

```
size_t letters = 0;
size_t i = 0;
while ( text[i] !='\0' )
{
    if ( isalnum( ( unsigned char )text[i++] ) )
    {
       letters++;
    }
}

printf( "%zu\n", letters );
```

Pay attention to that the function `isalnum` detects letters and digits. If you need to count only letters then use the function `isalpha`.

Comment: I had completely forgotten about casting, thank you Vlad!

Comment: @LauraT The casting issue is a good practice, but without it unless you are reading non-ASCII characters, then it won't have any impact on the operation of your code. It is a protection against a stray non-ASCII character in your input. Understand it for what it is. Your code wasn't misbehaving as a result of not casting to `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to count only letters:

```
size_t count_letters(const char *str)
{
    size_t count = 0;

    while(*str)
    {
        count += !!isalpha(*str++);
    }

    return count;
}
```

or if you prefer `for` loop

```
size_t count_letters_for_loop(const char *str)
{
    size_t count = 0;

    for(; *str; str++)
    {
        count += !!isalpha(*str);
    }

    return count;
}
```

As David suggested:

`!!` operation logically negates two times the value. As any logical operation gives 0 or 1, this double negation gives `1` for any non zero value or `0` for zero. It is needed as isalpha function *`Returns non-zero value if c is an alphabet, else it returns 0.`*

try to move such a logic to the separate functions. It is a very important skill in the `C` language

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip @P__J__! I intend to create separate functions for each element, but first I wanted to have a working letter counter, before I move it to its own function.

Comment: Better explain the `!!` - no doubt that would not be intuitive...

Answer (score 1):

You `while` loop has a flaw: you use the same variable to count the alphanumeric characters and to index the string. It only works if all characters are alphanumeric, otherwise you get an infinite loop because you stop incrementing `letter`.

You should use a `for` loop with an index `i`.

Also note that `isalnum()` all all functions from `<ctype.h>` are undefined for negative values, except `EOF`. On platforms where `char` is signed by default, some characters in the string may have negative values, causing undefined behavior if you pass them to `isalnum()`. You should cast `char` values as `(unsigned char)` to avoid this.

Here is a modified version.

```c
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) {
    string text = get_string("Text: ");
    printf("%s, \n", text);

    int letters = 0;
    for (int i = 0; text[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (isalnum((unsigned char)text[i])) {
            letters++;
        }
    }
    printf("%i\n", letters);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have found, since not all characters in your string are guaranteed to be alpha-number characters, your use of `letters` as a counter and an index is flawed. When you encounter a character that is not alpha and not a number, `if (isalnum(text[letters]))` tests false and `letters` is never incremented resulting in an infinite loop at that point. (you test the same character again on the next iteration -- with the same result -- and the scenery never changes....)

As all of the other very good and very correct answers suggest, just use a separate loop counter variable (or a pointer) and increment that to iterate over your string.

One other thing you might do to validate your logic (while outputting the `isalnum()` characters) is simply to do away with reprinting the original string with `printf` (you have that right in front of you from your entry), and instead output the characters that match your criteria. For example:

```
    for (int i = 0; text[i]; i++) {
        if (isalnum((unsigned char)text[i])) {
            putchar (text[i]);
            letters++;
        }
    }
```

That is just a slight variation on your output which serves double-duty providing your output and also providing confirmation of each character that matched the criteria used.

Also note, there is no need to `#include <string.h>` as there are no functions requiring its inclusion used in your code. With those changes a quick example could be:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) {

    int letters = 0;
    string text = get_string("Text: ");

    for (int i = 0; text[i]; i++) {
        if (isalnum((unsigned char)text[i])) {
            putchar (text[i]);
            letters++;
        }
    }

    printf (", %d\n", letters);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/ltrcountcs50-1
Text: 123.abc-456_def_*.*_789
123abc456def789, 15
```

**Moving Count Into A Function**

You can move your counting of alpha-num characters into a function easily. One benefit of passing your string to a function is the pointer received by the function is a copy of the pointer from `main()` (C is pass-by-value). That allows you to simply iterate with the parameter and return the count of alpha-num characters, e.g.

```
int countalnum (const char *s)
{
    int letters = 0;

    while (*s)
        if (isalnum((unsigned char)*s++))
            letters++;

    return letters;
}
```

(**note:** you must pass the parameter as `const char *` to use a pointer to constant char. You cannot use `const string` using the cs50 typedef. If you will not be changing the value passed in the function, passing as `const` allows the compiler to make optimization it would not otherwise be able to make)

With the function above, your code reduces to:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int countalnum (const char *s)
{
    int letters = 0;

    while (*s)
        if (isalnum((unsigned char)*s++))
            letters++;

    return letters;
}

int main(void) {

    string text = get_string("Text: ");

    printf ("%s, %d\n", text, countalnum(text));
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/ltrcountcs50-1
Text: 123.abc-456_def_*.*_789
123.abc-456_def_*.*_789, 15
```

But here, using the function results in printing the entire original string in `main()`. You can adjust the output as desired.

Answer (score 0):

You said being letters, and then you use `isalnum`?
so numbers will be counted as letters in your case
and you increment the value of the letters which the loop
counts on to iterate over the string only when it is a letter
so that leads to infinite loop when the condition is false
here is a solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int countLetters(char *str) {
  int letters = 0, ind = 0;
  while(str[ind] != '\0') 
    isalpha((unsigned char)str[ind++]) && letters++;
  return letters;
}

int main(void) {
  char text[100];
  fgets(text, sizeof(text), stdin);
  printf("%i", countLetters(text));
  return 0;
}
```

```
// input: hello 15-p */x
// output: 7
```

Comment: The decimal values for characters aren't guaranteed to be contiguous, though they are for ascii which is admittedly probably the most common set.

Comment: Ok I have fixed that

Comment: @chqrlie Ok I have edited my answer to cast to unsigned char and to use fgets instead of gets

Comment: @SaymoinSam: almost there: the code has undefined behavior if the input stream is an empty file.